# Second page with legend in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend

I would like to illustrate the following: on page 1 of my layout I need the map content on page 2 the legend only and nothing else.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Layouts are single pages. You'll need to create 2 layouts, one with your map frame and another with your layout. (Each layout will reference the same map).

I assume you're making a PDF because you want 2 or more pages. You'll need to combine the pages together into a single PDF.

There are Python commands you can use to combine multiple PDFs. See the [PDFDocument](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/pdfdocument-class.htm) class.